# Is the set of all rational sequences with constant tail countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am unable to prove or disprove that the set of all rational sequences with constant tail is countable. Precisely the set in question is

\begin{equation}
\{(x_n)_{n\ge1}: x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \, c \in \mathbb{Q} : \forall n > N : x_n = c\}
\end{equation}

What about when the tail is the same for all sequences? That is

\begin{equation}
\{(x_n)_{n\ge1}: x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n > N : x_n = 0\}
\end{equation}

Comment: I think, Since a rational sequence has constant tail thus it converges to a rational number, and rational number are countable , limits of the sequence are countable, Observe that for each sequence ,you have only finitely many unknown terms(1st term to the term after which terms become constant) which are also rational. therefore number of such sequences is also countable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $\mathbb Q$ is countable we may rewrite the question in terms of sequences over $\mathbb N$ and additionally it is then easy to give a bijection between the first set you mention and the set $\mathbb{N}^\ast$ of finite tuples over $\mathbb N$ by simply mapping a sequence $(x_1, ..., x_N, c, ...)$ to the tuple $(x_1, ..., x_N, c)$.

Now, to show that $\mathbb N^\ast$ is countable one can simply note that it is the countable union of countable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some rough steps, with details for you to fill in.

First consider the set $S_0$ of sequences with a constant $0$ tail. Find a bijection between $S_0$ and the set of *finite* sequences of rationals. Then prove that the set of finite sequences of rationals is countable.

Now, for a rational $c$, consider the set $S_c$ of sequences with constant tail $c$. Find a bijection between $S_c$ and $S_0$. Finally, the set of all sequences with constant tail is the union of $S_c$ for all rational $c$. Argue that this union is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the set of rational-valued sequences which are eventually constant and, for each $n\in \mathbf{N}$, let $\mathscr{A}_n$ be the set of all $x \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $x_{k}=x_n$ for all $k\ge n$. Then $\mathscr{A}=\bigcup_n \mathscr{A}_n$ and it is enough to show that each $\mathscr{A}_n$ is countable. To this aim, it is sufficient to see that
$$
\mathscr{A}_n=\bigcup_{q_1 \in \mathbf{Q}} \cdots \bigcup_{q_n \in \mathbf{Q}} \{x \in \mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{N}}: x_1=q_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}=q_{n-1}, x_k=q_n \text{ for all }k\ge n\}.
$$
for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Therefore each $\mathscr{A}_n$ is countable.

Basically, this is the reason why $(c, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is separable.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those sets are countable, and both of them can be *almost* identified with the set of all finite sequences of rational numbers.

In fact:

- In the first case look at the map which maps a finite sequence of length $n\ge 1$ to the infinite sequence where the last element is *repeated* ad infinitum.
- In the second case, look at the map that maps a finite sequence of length $n\ge 0$ to the infinite sequence made up by adding repeated zeros.

Both those maps are *onto* but not necessarily *1-1*, so your sets will be smaller than, or equal, to the size of the *set of all finite sequences of rational numbers*.

However, the latter is the union (for $n\ge 1$ or $n\ge 0$) of all sequences of rational numbers of size exactly $n$. Each of those sets has the same cardinality as $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\cdots\mathbb Q$ ($n$ times) and so is countable. (For $n=0$ it is an $1$-element set.) The resulting countable union of countable sets is therefore countable.